# Firebase phone authentication edits

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

[The display of verification codes: Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qug5b.jpg) how to change the sender name to app name when an OTP received from Firebase

Comment: Well... according to me the question is not unclear for what reason it has been put on hold. He simply wants to know how to change the sender name to app name when an `OTP` received from `Firebase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can’t** change the sender name.

The phone authentication method doesn't allow you to customize the OTP sms . You just have to deal with it.